# How to submit iframe code to mysqli table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to post iframe code to mysqli table.

When user entered video id in video id section, automatically insert id in iframe code (it means textarea section). when user selected video player youtube, the value of youtube is "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" is displayed in iframe, all results are real-time.

Please see this picture.

[image]

```html
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
  <h4 align="center">Videos Upload Portal</h4>
  <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Video ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" onchange="fillInTextArea(this);" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Video Title:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sname" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Video Category:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="continent" name="category" onchange="countryChange(this);" required>
    <option value="empty">Select Video Category</option>
    <option value="WWE">WWE</option>
    <option value="Movies">Movies</option>
    <option value="Cartoons">Cartoons</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Player Name:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="country" name="pname" onchange="fillInTextArea(this);" required>
    <option value="0">Select a player name</option>
    <option value="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/">Dailymotion</option>
    <option value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/">YouTube</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
    <label>Publish Date:</label>
    <input readonly value="..." class="form-control" type="text" type="text" name="date" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Video Length:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="part" required>
    <option>Part-1</option>
    <option>Part-2</option>
    <option>Part-3</option>
    <option>Part-4</option>
    <option>Part-5</option>
    <option>Part-6</option>
    <option>Part-7</option>
    <option>Part-8</option>
    <option>Part-9</option>
    <option>Part-10</option>
    <option>Part-11</option>
    <option>Part-12</option>
    <option>Part-13</option>
    <option>Part-14</option>
    <option>Part-15</option>
    <option>Part-16</option>
    <option>Full Show</option>
    <option>Full Match</option>
    <option>Full Movie</option>
    <option>Full Video</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Iframe Code:</label>
    <textarea name="iframe" id="iframe" class="form-control" rows="2">
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish 
    Video</button> <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Use domparser extract src from iframe.

Comment: 1. We do not reward begging 2. I formatted the form for you. Where is the relevant script? 3. What did you try and what went wrong? - please visit the [help] and see what and [ask] - post a [mcve]

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow, sorry for that, please i want a solution.